# Как убрать код из строки php

Tags: php

Нужно убрать

`<!-- Put this script tag to the <head> of your page --> <script type="text/javascript" src="//vk.com/js/api/openapi.js?137"></script> <!-- Put this div tag to the place, where the Poll block will be -->`

из строки с помощью php. Тот текст должен исчезнуть или заменится на пробел. Сама строка состоит из этого

```
<!-- Put this script tag to the <head> of your page -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="//vk.com/js/api/openapi.js?137"></script>
<!-- Put this div tag to the place, where the Poll block will be -->
<div id="vk_poll"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
VK.Widgets.Poll("vk_poll", {width: 300}, "252624848_44cf7d2c0b8ed9d470");
</script>
```

Comment: уберите теги javascript, jquery, api. Они не относятся к вашему вопросу. 
Используйте str_replace(), если хотите заменить всю строку.

Answer (score 0):

```
$main_string = '<!-- Put this script tag to the <head> of your page -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="//vk.com/js/api/openapi.js?137"></script>
<!-- Put this div tag to the place, where the Poll block will be -->
<div id="vk_poll"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
VK.Widgets.Poll("vk_poll", {width: 300}, "252624848_44cf7d2c0b8ed9d470");
</script>';
$pattern = '<!-- Put this script tag to the <head> of your page --> <script type="text/javascript" src="//vk.com/js/api/openapi.js?137"></script> <!-- Put this div tag to the place, where the Poll block will be -->';
$main_string = str_replace($pattern, '', $main_string);
```

Comment: Не знаю как вы получаете исходную строку и шаблон для поиска, но если просто присваиваете переменной в файле, не забудьте о символах перевода строки.